# Styling UL for Navigation Submenu

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a page where I have two vertical menus that each have a header, and then directly underneath navigation type links.

I'm using an UL for the two headers, and would like to use sub UL for the rest of each menu. I'm having a problem where the sub UL takes on the properties of the parent and is displyaing inline instead of vertically. Also, the submenu links are indenting instead of positioning directly under the headers. I'm still fairly new at CSS, so if I'm going about this incorrectly, I really appreciate any advice. Thanks for your help

```
#Contentmenu ul {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 40px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:960px;
    list-style-type: none; 
    list-style-image: none; 
}

#contentmenu li {
    display: inline; 
    padding:10px;  
    float: left;
}

#contentmenu a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    width:200px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:26px;
    background-color:#c7daff;
}


#Contentsubmenu ul {
    margin: 0; 
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:960px;
    list-style-type: none; 
    list-style-image: none; 
}

#contentsubmenu li {
    display:block;
    floa:left;
}

#contentsubmenu a {
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    color:#000000;
    font-size:20px;
    border-bottom:solid;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    background-color:#ffffff
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="contentmenu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Header 1</a>          
    <div id="contentsubmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Article 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" Article 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Articl3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS code is wrong at the element `#contentsubmenu li`. You use `floa: left;`, which is a incorrect CSS code. Additionally, just use `float: none;` on this element instead of `float: left;` and it will work as desired.

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KittMedia/T8Fzw/)

Therefore that you are new in CSS:
Try to write clean code with correct indentations.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is exactly what I am looking for. I am still in the learning stages of CSS, so I really appreciate your advice and input.

Comment: Then it would be helpful to set my answer as correct answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to only target the top-level , you would use this:

```
#contentmenu > ul
```

and

```
#contentmenu > ul > li
```

Also, CSS is case-sensitive, so make sure you are using *#contentmenu*

Does this fix your other issue as well?

Comment: In addition to your answer, the OP will probably need to remove padding on the contentsubmenu unordered list (ul) as browsers will normally add this as part of their user agent stylesheet (this should solve the indenting issue). There is also the "floa" typo spotted by KittMedia and a missing bracket on the "Article 2" (anchor) link. Good answer though, welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am still really green when it comes to CSS, so I appreciate all of the help and advice I can get.